# Return error in this "computepay" function

Tags: python

So I have this code that computes for your total money when you input hours and rate. Also if you work more than 40 hours you get 1.5 times rate per hours for each hour spent extra.

My question is I defined a function with this code:
and run it using computepay() the command prompt asks for
"Enter hours" 
"Enter Rate"

Then it quits without spitting out the value that I want. I am complete noob with programming so please help and patience is appreciated.
Thank you.

```
def computepay():
    try: 
        int1 = raw_input("Enter Hours")
        h = float(int1)
        int2= raw_input("Enter Rate")
        r = float(int2)
    except:
        print "Error, please enter a numeric input"
        quit()
    if h >= 40:
        pay1 = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5
        pay2 = h * r
        return pay1
    else:
        return pay2
```

Comment: How are you calling this? Do you ever e.g. `print` the value?

Answer (score 1):

"Then it quits without spitting out the value that I want". Yes it does, but if you don't display it somewhere you won't see it. IOW you'd need:

```
def computepay():
   # your code here

pay = computepay()
print "your pay is", pay
```

Now there's a mistake in your code:

```
if h >= 40:
    pay1 = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5
    pay2 = h * r
    return pay1
else:
    return pay2
```

You define `pay2` in the first part of the `if` branch but try to return it from the second - in which it doesn't exist. For any value of `h` < 40, this code will raise a `NameError`. What you want is:

```
if h >= 40:
    pay1 = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5
    return pay1
else:
    pay2 = h * r
    return pay2
```

which could be simplified to:

```
if h >= 40:
    return 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5
else:
    return h * r
```

And also there's something wrong (wrt/ good coding practices) with your code: asking the values for the computation and doing the computation itself should not be mixed in the same function, as it doesn't make your function testable (automated unit tests) nor reusable (with a different user interface). The "right way" is to split your code to decouple the computation from the way it's called:

```
def computepay(h, r):
    if h >= 40:
        return 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5
    else:
        return h * r


def main():
    try: 
        int1 = raw_input("Enter Hours")
        h = float(int1)
        int2= raw_input("Enter Rate")
        r = float(int2)

    # only catch the expected errors
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print "Error, please enter a numeric input"
        quit()

    print computepay(h, r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

By the  way you are doing you can call it as a function and print the functions return value

Without `print` you can not get the value so use print and `pay2` should be calculated in else case

```
def computepay():
    try: 
        int1 = raw_input("Enter Hours")
        h = float(int1)
        int2= raw_input("Enter Rate")
        r = float(int2)
    except:
        print "Error, please enter a numeric input"
        quit()
    if h >= 40:
        pay1 = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5

        return pay1
    else:
        pay2 = h * r
        return pay2
print computepay()
```

**or**

```
def computepay():
    try: 
        int1 = raw_input("Enter Hours")
        h = float(int1)
        int2= raw_input("Enter Rate")
        r = float(int2)
    except:
        print "Error, please enter a numeric input"
        quit()
    if h >= 40:
        pay1 = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5

        print pay1
    else:
        pay2 = h * r
        print pay2
computepay()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning `pay2` for `else` condition

```
if h >= 40:
    pay1 = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5
    return pay1
else:
    pay2 = h * r
    return pay2
```

Comment: Wow this is like my second time posting on stackoverflow and I am so glad there are great people to help me. I read all your post and learned some great knowledge thank you so much! I figured out my problem. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine:

```
def computepay():
try: 
    int1 = raw_input("Enter Hours")
    h = float(int1)
    int2= raw_input("Enter Rate")
    r = float(int2)
except:
    print "Error, please enter a numeric input"
    quit()

if h <= 40:
    pay = h * r
else:
    pay = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5
return pay

print computepay()
```

Note: Don't forget to call `computepay()` with `print` statement to get the function's returned results to the output device i.e. to the consol.

**Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)**

Answer (score 0):

After dealing the same issue, i suggest you to follow this code:

```html
def computepay(hours,rate):
  print ("In compute pay hours=", hours, " rate=", rate)
  pay = rate * hours
  if hours > 40:
       pay = rate * (40) + rate * 1.5 * (h - 40)
  return(pay)

hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
rate=input("Enter Rate:")
h = float(hrs)
r = float(rate)
p=computepay(h,r)
print('Pay: ', p)

## try & except:
try:
  inp = h
  hours = float(inp)
  inp2 = r
  rate = float(inp2)

except:
  print ("Error, please enter numeric input")
  quit()
```

[image: E.G]

Answer (score -1):

def computepay():

```
try:
    hours = raw_input("Enter hours:")
    h = float(hours)
    rate = raw_input("Enter rate:")
    r = float(rate)

except:
    print ("Error, enter numeric value please:")
    quit()
if h >=40:
    pays = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5
    return pays

else:
    pays2 = h * r
    return pays2
```

print (computepay())

## This works 100%